# Which was the first aeroplane to have fuel tanks within its wings?

Tags: aviation-history, fuel-tanks

Wings with substantial thickness start appearing after WW1, with Junkers pioneering all-aluminium aircraft such as the [Junkers F 13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junkers_F_13) (1919). It as a far from universal trend, however; compare with the  [de Havilland Hercules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Havilland_Hercules) airliner of 1926, which was presumably designed to go as far as possible.

So it seems likely that using the wing volume for fuel must have come later - clearly, simply increasing wing thickness doesn't mean you can start filling it with fuel: there are structural implications too.

Which was the first plane to have a substantial volume of its wings used as fuel tanks? That is, not just the part that is absorbed by the fuselage.

[image: Junkers F 13]
Junkers F 13 (first flight - 1919) - [source](https://www.gq-magazine.co.uk/article/rimowa-f13)

[image: de Havilland Hercules]
de Havilland DH.66 Hercules (first flight - 1926) - [source](https://www.dehavilland.co.za/DH66_Hercules.html)

Comment: "RIMOWA The luggage with the grooves". Interesting... are they claiming the Junkers is "luggage"? `</OT>`

Comment: Rimowa is a luggage company, their products have grooves in them. That's probably why they chose the Junkers for their ads.

Comment: Start from the Spirit of St Louis and go back from there.